# ¿Como hacer que mi Guardian de Angular me permita acceder a la view que esta bloqueando?

Tags: nodejs, angular, guards

Tengo un formulario login de Administrador con email y password. Cuando se ingresan estos datos,
utilizo el servicio `authService.getAdmin(email, password)`, este servicio envia los datos a `NodeJs`
para comprobar si el admin existe, si existe me devuelve los datos del admin.
Cuando `Angular` recibe la respuesta de que existe el admin, redirige automaticamente a la view de administrador `admin-principal`.
Hasta este punto lo pude lograr. El problema esta en que ahora, esa view `admin-principal` esta protegida con un `Guardian`,
y lo que necesitaria lograr es que, cuando `Angular` sepa de que el admin existe, el guardian me permita acceder a la view.

aca mi `app-routing.module.ts` donde tengo el `Guardian` en el `path: admin-principal`

```js
import { AdminGuard } from './admin.guard';
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'admin-login',
    component: AdminLoginComponent
  },
  {
    path: '',
    component: AdminLayoutComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'admin-principal',
        pathMatch: 'full',
      },
      {
        path: 'admin-principal',
        canActivate: [AdminGuard],
        component: AdminPrincipalComponent
      },
    ]
  },
];
```

Aca mi guardian `admin.guard.ts`

```js
canActivate(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree {
    return false;
  }
```

aca mi servicio `auth.service.ts`

```js
API = 'http://localhost:4000/admin/login';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getAdmin(email: string, pass: string) {
    const state: boolean = true;
    // console.log(state, email, pass);
    return this.http.post<Admin[]>(this.API, {email, pass, state});
  }
```

aca mi  `admin-login.component.ts`

```js
 export class AdminLoginComponent implements OnInit {

  form: FormGroup;
  admin = {} as Admin;
  adminExist: boolean = true;

  constructor(
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    // public adminService: AdminService,
    private authService: AuthService,
    private router: Router
    ) {
    this.buildForm();
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  buildForm() {
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(50)]],
      password: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(50)]],
    });
  }

  login(event: Event){
    event.preventDefault();
    if (this.form.valid){
      const email = this.form.get('email').value;
      const pass = this.form.get('password').value;
      this.authService.getAdmin(email, pass)
      .subscribe(admin => {
        // si no obtuvo el admin
        if (admin.length === 0){
          this.adminExist = false;
          console.log('no existe el administrador');
        }
        else{
          console.log(admin);
          sessionStorage.setItem('adminEmail', admin[0].email);
          this.router.navigateByUrl('admin-principal');
        }
    });
    }
  }
```

aca el formulario en `admin-login.component.html`

```html
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="login($event)">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="email" class="form-control" formControlName="email" (ngModelChange)="adminExist = true" placeholder="@email">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="password" class="form-control" formControlName="password" (ngModelChange)="adminExist = true" placeholder="password">            
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary table">Login</button>
</form>
<div *ngIf="!adminExist">
    <p class="text-center text-danger">No existe el administrador</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hay varias cuestiones de seguridad a tomar en cuenta para el control de usuarios, contraseñas y sesiones que no se están tomando en consideración.

Pero para responder tu pregunta: podés aprovechar que estás guardando en el `sesionStorage` la información del admin para utilizar esa data en el guardian:

```js
canActivate(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree {
       return sessionStorage.getItem('adminEmail');
  }
```

Con lo que estás diciendo "si existe la información del admin en el sesionStorage, es porque ha iniciado sesión.

---

Por otro lado también podés hacer uso del `AuthService` para guardar/obtener esa información.

Comment: Gracias @Nery Ortez excelente!, tienes razón cuando dices que Hay varias cuestiones de seguridad a tomar en cuenta para el control de usuarios, contraseñas y sesiones que no estoy tomando en consideración. ya que estoy aprendiendo Angular. El administrador seria yo solo, por eso queria algo simple, cuando haga la parte de usuarios, si voy a tener en cuenta otro tipo de consideraciones, gracias por tu aporte!

Comment: A la orden!
Si la respuesta te ayudó podés marcarla como aceptada para ayudar a otros

Answer (score 0):

La solución fue en la `funcion login`, si el admin existe, guardo los datos en una `sessionStorage`. En mi caso guarde un `objeto` en la `sessionStorage`, para tener toda la informacion del admnistrador.

```js
login(event: Event){
    event.preventDefault();
    if (this.form.valid){
      const email = this.form.get('email').value;
      const pass = this.form.get('password').value;
      this.authService.getAdmin(email, pass)
      .subscribe(admin => {
        // si no obtuvo el admin
        if (admin.length === 0){
          this.adminExist = false;
          console.log('no existe el administrador');
        }
        else{
          // objeto Admin
          let admi = {} as Admin;
          admin.forEach(element => {
            admi = element;
          });
          console.log(admi);
          // sessionStorage solo permite guardar un string, como yo quiero guardar un objeto de tipo Admin
          // tengo que usar JSON.stringify(admi)
          sessionStorage.setItem('adminData', JSON.stringify(admi));
          this.router.navigateByUrl('admin-principal');
        }
    });
    }
  }
```

en `admin.guard.ts` pregunto si la `sessionStorage('adminData')` existe. Si existe hago un return true para habilitar la view.

```js
canActivate(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree {
    /* esta sessionStorage se crea en admin-login.component.ts, cuando el email y password
      son correctos*/
      if (sessionStorage.getItem('adminData') === null){
        return false;
      }
      else{
        return true;
      }
    }
```